# CleanUp Policy needed for Nexus Repository 3.61.0-02

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

I need a clean up policy for Nexus, I created some policies on UI but the problem is, there is no much of option on UI so what i need is it should delete components that is older than 30 days but should keep last 3 components no matter what.